# React-Slick with IntersectionObserver not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer, react-slick

I'm trying to animate my `react-slick` slides when they enter into the viewport by detecting when the slide elements intersect with my root element using the `IntersectionObserver` API.

This is working as expected.

What isn't working is, when `react-slick` loops back from `:last-slide` to  `:first-slide`, that first react component seems to lose its state momentarily before "catching up" - even though it has already been rendered.

I've demonstrated this in two places, once using the native IntersectionObserver API and once using a React Wrapper around the native API - `react-intersection-observer`.

The full code of what I have so far is below and in the sandboxes here:

Native: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-and-native-intersection-observer-cqtmv
React Wrapper: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-and-react-intersection-observer-qvbum

```
const ReactSlickDemo = () => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      flexWrap: "wrap",
      "& > *": {
        margin: theme.spacing(0.5)
      }
    },
    container: {
      padding: "40px",
      background: "#419be0",
      "& .slick-slide img": {
        margin: "auto"
      }
    },
    initFadeIn: {
      "& *": {
        opacity: 0,
        "& img": {
          opacity: 1
        },
        "& [class*=SWRecordHeader-images-]": {
          opacity: 1
        }
      },
      "& [class*=SWRecordHeader-inner-]": {
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
    runFadeIn: {
      "& *": {
        opacity: 1
      }
    },
    initSlideUp: {
      "& *": {
        webkitTransform: "translateY(30px)",
        transform: "translateY(30px)",
        "& img": {
          webkitTransform: "translateY(-30px)",
          transform: "translateY(-30px)"
        },
        "& [class*=SWRecordHeader-images-]": {
          webkitTransform: "unset",
          transform: "unset"
        }
      }
    },
    runSlideUp: {
      "& *": {
        webkitTransform: "translateY(0px)",
        transform: "translateY(0px)",
        "& img": {
          webkitTransform: "translateY(0px)",
          transform: "translateY(0px)"
        }
      }
    },
    initTransition: {
      "& *": {
        webkitTransition: "all 0.6s ease-in-out",
        transition: "all 0.6s ease-in-out"
      }
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();

  const Component = () => {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);
    const el = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("effect!");
      const node = el.current;
      const options = {
        threshold: 0.5
      };
      const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
        entries.forEach(entry => {
          if (entry.isIntersecting && !toggle) setToggle(true);
          console.log(toggle);
        });
      }, options);
      observer.observe(node);
      return () => observer.unobserve(node);
    }, [toggle, el]);

    return (
      <div
        ref={el}
        className={clsx(
          classes.initTransition,
          classes.initFadeIn,
          classes.initSlideUp,
          {
            [classes.runFadeIn]: toggle,
            [classes.runSlideUp]: toggle
          }
        )}
      >
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" alt="test" />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <Slider dots>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4].map(item => (
          <Component />
        ))}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};
```